# how to add java system property named: `-DurlParams=intent=REGULAR&auto=w1`

Tags: java, bash, shell, intellij-idea

I try to run a `sh script` to run my jar

when I configure it in intelliJ like this

when i copy-pase the same values to a `sh` file and run it from the terminal

```
java -Dhostname=23.251.137.64  -DclientLocation=34.880272,32.195748  -DqueryString=Haifa -DurlParams=intent=REGULAR&auto=w1 -DisAlongRout=false -Dproviders=p1,p2 -cp RTMonitor.jar com.w.monitoring.headlessclient.HCRunner HeadlessClientE2ET#sendSearchRequest
```

I get this error:

```
 Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server   to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server,
                  because you are running on a server-class machine.

....
```

I tried to eliminate some java system properties and when I removed `DurlParams=intent=REGULAR&auto=w1` it seems the jar is runnning

how can i fix the `DurlParams=intent=REGULAR&auto=w1` system property to still be in the running script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-DurlParams=intent\=REGULAR\&auto\=w1`